# ASP MVC with ie 8 not returning value from hidden field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8

I have a view that isn't working for some of our customers, but it does work for others. Eventally (I believe) I have tracked this down to an issue with ie8 over more modern browsers.

This project has to use IE, and for legacy reasons, this customer has to use ie 8, so please don't turn this into a browser discussion.

The problem line is;

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CustomerPresent, new { @name = "CustomerPresent" })
```

The javascript that toggles the value works (as checked by inspection of the html).

But when the form is submitted, I always get a value of false back for the hidden field, even if it has been set to true on the page.

I then cut out the html helper, and replaced it with;

```
<input type="hidden" name="CustomerPresent" id="CustomerPresent" value=@Model.CustomerPresent />
```

Again though, when the form is posted back, the CustomerPresent field is false, even if it was set to true on the page.

This is only an issue for the one customer, but they are a big one, so how do I create a work round to fix this.

[Update]
Using Dev Tools, I have seen that the request does not contain &CustomerPresent= for ie8, but it is present for ie11.

[update] Added js as requested

```
 function signNow(customerPresent) {
    document.getElementById('CustomerPresent').value = customerPresent;
}
```

and the button calls are;

```
<button id="signButtonNotPresent" onclick="signNow('false');return false;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="button">Customer Not Present</button>

<button id="signButton" onclick="signNow('true');return false;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary pull-right" type="button">Customer Is Present</button>
```

Comment: What name does the system generate on the page if you just just `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CustomerPresent);` -- wondering if you're changing the name to something other than what the model binding expects it to be? Is the hidden element actually inside the form that's getting posted back?

Comment: Using Emulation mode in ie11, I can see that if I use a browser version later than 8, then the hidden field is returned in the request body. If I set it to ie 8 then the field is not present, and thus as a bool is defaulting to false when it hits the controller action

Comment: Try enclosing value with double-quotes?

Comment: `new { @name = "CustomerPresent" }` is pointless - it does nothing

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, not relevent to the issue, but worth knowing if it saves on typing :-)

Comment: @TZHX, name and id are the same no matter which way I try it. Only difference is the manual one doesn't have the additional html5 attributes.

Comment: How do you set the `value` attribute to "True"?

Comment: @StephenMuecke tehres some basic js that does that. I can see in the DOM explorer that the hidden field value is being set, it is just not being passed back.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that problem, but as a quick workaround you could use this: `<input type="text" style="display:none" name="CustomerPresent" id="CustomerPresent" value=@Model.CustomerPresent />`

Comment: @TZHX Changing to single or doubel quotes has no impact, nor does omitting value=...

Comment: Not working either @ChrisRedhead

Comment: @Matt Can you open the IE developer tools to see what values gets sent over the wire. Also post your JS code as well as your controller code!!!!

Comment: @heymega As I have already stated in comments, the parameter does not appear in the request for ie8, but does for ie11. (checked using dev tools.). DOM value is being set via javascript, it is just not being passed back.

Comment: @Matt Can you not give us the JS?

Comment: @heymega done, for what its worth

Comment: @Matt have you tried changing it to a Html.TextBoxFor and see if you're getting the same issue?

Comment: @Matt Is the POST a standard form POST or is there any JS/Ajax involved?

Comment: @Carl No Ajax or JS.